# Why are newly added APIs annotated with @hide in Android framework still added to current.txt after a make update-api?

Tags: android, android-build

I'm an Android framework developer. Recently I'm inspecting codes about adding new public APIs to AOSP, and make sure all these public APIs hidden, that is to say keeping the current.txt the same with AOSP.

Now I have encountered a problem that really confuses me. As we all know, public APIs with @hide annotated will not be added to current.txt, which will be generated after a make update-api, but there seems to be an exception here.

We have some codes out of frameworks/base, which will be compiled together into framework.jar by specifying the extra source files in Android.mk, like below:

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += \
        $(call all-java-files-under,../../flyme/frameworks/base/core) \
        $(call all-java-files-under,../../flyme/frameworks/base/media) \
        $(call all-java-files-under,../../flyme/frameworks/common/media) \
        $(call all-java-files-under,../../flyme/frameworks/common/core)
```

What confuses me is, new public APIs added by these extra codes will be output into current.txt, no matter using **@hide** or not. I have thought that DroidDoc is not able to remove @hide stuff from codes out of frameworks/base but I'm not sure about this. Thanks a lot!